# Share on Facebook button with image from within an email

Tags: facebook, email, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I send an email to users by using mailgun.
The email consists of some text and multiple images (integrated like )

I would like to add a Share button which leads the user to facebook and automatically adds the image(s) to the post. also it would be great to add a link to a website.

As I understand, facebook sharing needs a website to crawl for Open Graph tags but the email is no website to crawl, right?
Also I've read that facebook discontinued the sharer.php which seem to accept parameters.
I tested the sharer.php and it still seems to work. Does anyone know how to add one or more image links to this url? I guess I have to format the link somehow. Will this work in the future or will they remove it?
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=123.abc.com&t=Test

Any idea how I can let my users share the images I sent them via mail other than having them download the images and upload it manually to facebook?

Thank you so much in advance,
Robert

I tested
[https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=123.abc.com&t=Test&picture={a](https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=123.abc.com&t=Test&picture=%7Ba) link to the picture}
but even when I use urlencoder.org to encode my url, I can't see the image.
I guess this tool is deprecated but how can I add a share button nowadays?

Comment: The sharer is not deprecated, but dynamically passing title, description and thumbnail via parameters is. Facebook now only takes this data from the OG meta tags the URL returns. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/#markup

Comment: So the only way is to have a website? 
My idea now is to create a php website and pass it all my needed parameters like encoded image urls, title, description and let the php script generate the og: meta tags. then link this dynamic page with my share button.

Comment: Sharing always requires a URL _to_ share. You can not upload any photos directly using the dialogs.